# Having a Java class where one of the fields is a method?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, field

I'm pretty new to Java, as the nature of my post will give away

I need to create a class which contains a set of methods which can easily be extended by a programmer, should it be needed. I thought about having two classes: `Commands` and `Command`. `Commands` contains an array of `Command` objects, and is where the programmer can add new commands. The `Command` class has two fields. The name of the class, and a method signature. I'm not sure how this can be done. In C, I think you can have a struct of functions, so can we have a class where the instances of the class are methods? Or am I completely on the wrong track?

I thought about trying to do something like this:

```
public class Commands
{
    private ArrayList<Command> commands;

    /**
     * Constructor for objects of class Command
     */
    public Commands()
    {
        createCommands();
    }

    /**
     * This is where a programmer can add new commands
     */
    public void createCommands()
    {
        commands.add(new Command("move", public void move()));
    }

    /**
     * This is where the programmer can define the move command
     */
    public void move()
    {
        ....
    }
}

public class Command
{
    private String command_name;
    private Method command;

    public Command(String command_name, Method command)
    {
        this.command_name = command_name;
        this.command = command;
    }
}
```

I know there are a lot of things wrong with this, but I'm stuck on finding the right way. Hints/help would be fantastic.

Comment: What is the overall goal you are trying to achieve with this?

Comment: there will be a number of commands, and the user can execute them by typing "execute name_of_command". the commands will be defined in the Commands class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java does not have function pointers. This is a common trick:

```
abstract class (or interface) Command {
  void execute();
}

public void createCommands() {
  commands.add(new Command(){ 
      @Override
      void execute() {
        something.move();
      }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I think you want to use the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

> In object-oriented programming, the
>   command pattern is a design pattern in
>   which an object is used to represent
>   and encapsulate all the information
>   needed to call a method at a later
>   time

The Wikipedia page has an example.

Your `Command` should be an interface with an `execute` method. A programmer can code a class that implements the `Command` interface, and thus she/he must implement the `execute` method to do what is needed. You can then have a `Command[]` array, and for each `Command` object you can simply call `execute` to perform the task.

Comment: Many thanks. That was a big help, and I think it's worked. The only thing now is that I need to be able to name the commands so that the user can execute them by typing "execute name_of_command". I'm trying to use a HashMap to store the names and commands. I'll see how I go

Comment: You're welcome! Using a `Map` to associate user-friendly names of commands with the corresponding `Command` objects is a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't have function pointers, so this doesn't work. What you probably want to do is have a Command *interface* with an `execute()` method that you implement in concrete subclasses.

It's a matter of style, but I usually wouldn't have a name field in the Command implementations. Rather, I would just create a `Map<String, Command>` that holds the name for each Command.

Comment: edit: I had a problem with using the Map as you suggest, but I think I got it working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can't directly pass methods about in Java. Instead, they will need to be objects that implement a common interface. For example, your methods could become objects that implement the Runnable interface. Then you just call "run" when you need to use the method.